# VBA, looping through all tabs to hide rows based on cell values "HIDE"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a code to hide rows based on a "HIDE" value in column "AC" on all tabs. I can't get this code to loop through all worksheets. I know the ActiveSheet is probably part of the problem but it's the only way I can get it to hide rows on any of the sheets.

```
Sub HideRows()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For I = 1 To WS_Count

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("AC5:AC14")
        With cell
            .EntireRow.Hidden = .Value = "HIDE"
        End With
    Next
    Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `ActiveSheet.Range("AC5:AC14")` to `Sheets(I).Range("AC5:AC14")`

Comment: Or, if you wish to have the active sheet change to the one your code is currently working on, add `Sheets(I).Activate` before your inner for each loop. The solution given by @ScottCraner is better practice however.

Comment: That worked perfectly Scott, thank you.  Now I'm trying to hide columns based on values in P33:Y33.  I changed the range and EntireRow.Hidden to EntireColumn.Hidden but it wont work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.

```
Sub HideRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim actCell As Range


    For Each ws In Worksheets
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Get the last row of the table

        For Each actCell In ws.Range("AC5:AC" & lastRow) 'Iterate from row 5 until the last row of the table, if you have an fixed range just change it to Range("AC5:AC14") for example.
            With actCell
                If ws.Range("AC" & .Row) = "HIDE" Then
                    .EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: why add `lastRow` variable when user has range specifically defined?

Comment: To make it dynamic, what if he add more rows?

Comment: yes that could be a reason, but if he has rows there already that he doesn't want to evaluate (and they say "HIDE"), the code will hide them toot. I think it's worth explaining what you did and why you did so the OP can take the information as he needs it.